# Understanding the square of x+dx

Tags: calculus

I'm currently reading "Calculus made Easy" - http://calculusmadeeasy.org/2.html

It describes a quantity `x` that can grow by a small amount to become `x + dx`.

It then defines the square of this to be `x^2 + 2x · dx + (dx)^2`.

Could somebody explain or point me to a resource that explains how/why/the process of how the square of `x + dx` came to be `x^2 + 2x · dx + (dx)^2`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you really asking why the formula $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ is true?  $(x+dx)^2 = (x+dx)(x+dx) = x(x+dx) + dx(x+dx) = (x^2 + xdx) + (dx\cdot x + (dx)^2) = x^2 + 2xdx + (dx)^2$. That that basic quadratic expansion.

Comment: @fleablood no - I'm not  asking why it is true, I am asking how `x + dx` becomes `x^2 + 2x · dx + (dx)^2` when squared, e.g what are the steps. I don't doubt it is in-fact true :) - it may be basic to some, but it is not basic to me, hence my question, to better understand what I don't :)

Comment: Uh.... just *do* it.   $(x+dx)^2 = (x+dx)\times (x+dx) = x(x+dx) + dx(x+dx) = (x^2 + xdx) + (xdx + (dx)^2) = x^2 +2xdx + (dx)^2$.   Just like $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab +b^2$.  Haven't you done this thousands of times before?  Why is this time any different?

Comment: I haven't done this thousands of times unfortunately, I'm new to all of this, thankyou for your explanations!

Comment: So.... You've never seen $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much discussion we realized you were reading

> $x^2 + 2x\cdot + (dx)^2$

as

> $(x^2 + 2x)\cdot(dx + (dx)^2)$

which is wrong

Instead of as

> $[x^2]  +  [2x\ dx] + [(dx)^2]$

which is right.

....

If $x$ and $dx$ are treated as numbers then $(x+dx) = x^2 + 2x\ dx + (dx)^2$.  Just like $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab +b^2$.  That's all there is to it.

====

Is it that the $2x$ is clumped to one side and the $dx$ is separate with a $\cdot$ between them that is throwing you.

This is the basic quadratic expansion.

$(a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b) = a(a+b)+b(a+b) = (a^2 + ab)+(ab + b^2) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

So if we assume , as this text irritatingly does, that $dx$ is some really small number then

$(x+dx)^2 = x^2 + 2\cdot x \cdot dx + (dx)^2$

Is it that $x^2 + 2x\cdot dx + (dx)^2$ looks like $x^2 + (2x)\cdot(dx) + (dx)^2$ and it looks ... weird... because too much attention is drawn to the $2x$ being a single thing?  If so..... well, it *looks* weird but that's just type-setting.  The author wasn't trying to say anything odd.

Comment: Excuse me very much. What is the dot on d ($\dot{d}$)?

Comment: AH, I think this explains it, it isn't `2x` it is `2 * x`, making it actually: `x^2 + 2 * x  * dx + (dx)^2` - right?

Comment: Unless parenthesis are specifically stated, a mulitplicatio sign refers only to the terms in a cluster.  It doesn't refer to sums.   $a^2 + 2a\cdot b + b^2$ means $(a^2) + (2ab) + b^2$.  It *never* means $(a^2 + 2a)\cdot (b + b^2)$.  If you want the latter you must put in parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, but to interpret it as $(x^2 + 2x)(dx + x^2)$ was a very *weird* and unnatural way to interpret it that we had *no* idea what you were thinking.  Out of curiosity, why *did* you interpret it that way?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is just a case of expanding the expression $(a+b)^2$.

I.e. $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 +2ab$

Just replace the symbols in the equation for $x$ and $dx$. There is nothing special about the expansion (meaning it is just algebraic manipulation, it is not something unique or special pertaining to calculus).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, is there any way you could show the steps taken to expand `x + dx` - I'm struggling to understand where the multiplication came from in the expansion.

Comment: Sure, when you say multiplication do you mean you are unsure on why exactly we are multiplying $x+dx$ with itself?

Comment: @JacobClark I have just seen your comment on your question; I think I understand what you mean. The point that is being made is to consider how the area of the square changes for some small change $dx$. Look at figure 2 in your source. Do you see where the terms come from? $x+dx$ is the length of the square, the result you asked about is the area of the square.

Comment: - I suppose in your example of the expansion of `(a + b)2 = (+)2=2+2+2` there is no multiplication here, and I understand that fine, however `x + dx` results in `x^2 + 2x` multiplied by `dx + (dx)^2` - and it is this multiplication I don't understand - thanks!

Comment: @JacobClark I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean when you say 'there is no multiplication'. $(a+b)^2$ IS multiplication. We use this formula of $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$ because in the context of what you are trying to learn, the AREA of the square is important, so we multiply!

Comment: What do you mean $(x+dx)^2$ results in $(x^2 + 2x)$ multiplied by $(dx + (dx)^2)$?  No, it doesn't.   Let $a = x$ and let $b = dx$ then $(a+b)^2 =a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (x)^2 + 2(x)(dx) + (dx)^2$.  And $(x+dx)^2 = (x+dx)\times (x+dx)$.  There's nothing weird going on.

Comment: I think @fleablood has correctly understood your misunderstanding

Comment: Okay..     You book says quote $x^2 + 2x \cdot dx + (dx)^2$ unquote and you are incorrectly interpretting this as $(x^2 + 2x)\cdot(dx + (dx)^2)$.  That is NOT what the author means.  The author means $(x^2) + (2\times x \times dx) + ((dx)^2)$.  This is *EXACTLY* the same thing as $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab +b^2$.  The EXACT SAME THING.

Comment: AH, I understand now, is there a special name for the formula `(a+b)^2`?  It is worth noting I am not in any way misunderstanding that these two things are not the same things, I just don't understand how/why they came to be, what their names are or how I can research more about them.

Comment: I call it the quadratic expansion.  It's a basic formula and a direct response of the distributive property of multiplication.  $(a + b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b)$ and by distribution this is $a(a+b) + b(a+b) = (a^2 + ab) + (ab + b^2)$ and by associative regrouping $a^2 +(ab+ab) + b^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.  Have you honestly never seen that proven before?

Comment: Never seen it before in my life - I'm 26!

Comment: It's used in algebra *all* the time.  It's so fundamental it's stated as something univerally obvious.  It's how we complete the square and do the quadratic equation.  Have you ever taken high school algebra yet?  If you want a graphic proof, look at that picture of a square.  A square with sides $(x+dx)$ is broken int a square with side $x$ (so area is $x^2$) and two rectangles with sides $x$ and $dx$ (so area is $x\cdot dx$ and $x\cdot dx$ or $2(x\cdot dx)$) and a square with sid $dx$ (so area is $(dx)^2$).  So the area of a square $x+dx$ is $x^2$plus $2xdx$ plus $(dx)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

He has simply *formally* expanded the expression $$(x+\mathrm dx)^2$$ in accordance with the usual rules.